# How to chose a random word from a list in a file with an especific lenght in python

Tags: python, random, word-list

Im very new on python, actually, Im not even a programer, Im a doctor :), and as a way to practice I decided to wright my hangman version.
After some research I couldnt find any way to use the module "random" to return a word with an especific length. As a solution, I wrote a routine in which it trys a random word till it found the right lenght. It worked for the game, but Im sure its a bad solution and of course it affects the performance. So, may someone give me a better solution? Thanks.

There is my code:

```
import random

def get_palavra():
    palavras_testadas = 0
    num_letras = int(input("Choose the number of letters: "))
    while True:
        try:
            palavra = random.choice(open("wordlist.txt").read().split())
            escolhida = palavra
            teste = len(list(palavra))
            if teste == num_letras:
                return escolhida
            else:
                palavras_testadas += 1
            if palavras_testadas == 100:  # in large wordlists this number must be higher
                print("Unfortunatly theres is no words with {} letters...".format(num_letras))
                break
            else:
                continue
        except ValueError:
            pass

forca = get_palavra()
print(forca)
```

Comment: You can organize your words in separate lists, so that one list has only words of a certain length. Then choose random among them.

Comment: If your code works without errors, a better place to ask is [codereview.se].

Comment: Why did you change your accepted answer  ? ;) Because ... the answer your accepted has 2 mistakes that make the code wrong and it does not even compile

Comment: Im new on python and very new on stackoverflow... I thought it was just a thanks for the answer but. Your code is running perfect for code. Sorry about it and thank you.

Comment: My code works fine now, and is more direct and simple than azros’s answer

Comment: In azro’s answer, if one line has multiple words it will not find all words in a line, you will be missing words. So azro’s code is not the best answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You may

1. read the file once and store the content
2. remove the newline `\n` char fom each line, because it count as a character
3. to avoid making `choice` on lines that hasn't the good length, filter first to keep the possible ones
4. if the `good_len_lines` list has no element you directly know you can stop, no need to do a hundred picks
5. else, pick a word in the good_length ones

```
def get_palavra():
    with open("wordlist.txt") as fic:                                      # 1.
        lines = [line.rstrip() for line in fic.readlines()]                # 2.
    num_letras = int(input("Choose the number of letters: "))
    good_len_lines = [line for line in lines if len(line) == num_letras]   # 3.
    if not good_len_lines:                                                 # 4.
        print("Unfortunatly theres is no words with {} letters...".format(num_letras))
        return None
    return random.choice(good_len_lines)                                   # 5.
```

Comment: @MarcusVinicius Exactly

Comment: You did not take into consideration that a line might have more than one word, you just used readlines() to extract the whole line as one word

Comment: @DiegoSuarez at no moment is was mentionned that several word could be on one line. I won’t handle case just because they "could exist" in another usecase

Answer (score -1):

Here is a working example:

```
def random_word(num_letras):
    all_words = []
    with open('wordlist.txt') as file:
        lines = [ line for line in file.read().split('\n') if line ] 
        for line in lines:
            all_words += [word for word in line.split() if word]
    words = [ word for word in all_words if len(word) == num_letras ]
    if words:
        return random.choice(words)
```

Comment: Your code has 2 mistakes. It does not compile and so does not answer the OP's problem